# Use the spacebar and `w`

Tags: terminal

With the view to learn how to use the command `less`, there's an exercise which says "*Do the exercise again, but this time page through it. On Unix you use the spacebar and `w` (the letter w) to go down and up. Arrow keys also work*". Could anyone be able what it means by "*use the spacebar and `w`*"

Comment: Open a file with `less`. Hit the spacebar. Now hit `w`. They’re keys.

Comment: If you press the space bar, it will page down. If you press the letter `w` key, it will page up.